# VLC playing HTTP video stream from netty server: Connection reset by peer

Tags: http, streaming, netty, vlc, vlcj

I need to extend the basic netty HTTP file server (https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/file) to stream a video through HTTP after I have done some custom encoding to the video. I'm planning to write a Java application that use vlcj to reproduce the stream.

However, even before starting the extension of the file server, I'm experiencing a strange behavior. By using the basic server example (both with netty 3.6.5 and netty 4.0.0.CR1) when I use VLC (version 2.0.6) to play the file the following happens:

- VLC is able to start reproducing the file
- As soon as I seek through the file a couple of times i get the following error: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer

While playing the same stream with mpc-hc (http://mpc-hc.org/) I do not experience this problem.

Do I need to configure something the server in some particular way for allowing VLC to play correctly the stream? I haven't found any particular information in both VLC and VLCJ website/forums.

Any hint/suggestion is accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not enough to simply start up a basic http file server for streaming video to the VLCj player.

The server must be able to handle "range requests".  During a range request, the VLC player requests the specific portion of the video that it wants to play next (a byte range such as bytes 3212-5678).  The video player will make repeated range requests during playback even if the initial request was for all bytes.

When you seek, the video player will make a range request to your server for the next portion of the file.  If your server cannot handle the request, the player will have behavior like you describe. (i.e. Connection rest by peer)

Hope that helps.